# No matches for kind "ReplicaSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to run Replica Set.

I have this yaml file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: nginxrs
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      name: nginx
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.12-alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

This file is called `nginx-rs.yaml`

Next, In terminal use command

```
 kubectl apply -f nginx-rs.yaml
```

And I have this error

```
error: unable to recognize "nginx-rs.yaml": no matches for kind "ReplicaSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
```

Thanks for pointing out where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In [kubernetes 1.16](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/) replicaset was moved to `apps/v1` `apiVersion` from `extensions/v1beta1`. Hence the yaml should be as below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: nginxrs
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      name: nginx
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.12-alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```